# Properly reference exported variable within bash code

Tags: linux, bash, sh, shortcut

I have created this "bookmarks" program:
https://github.com/PyTis/PyTis/blob/development/src/bootstrap-box/home-jlee/bashrc/bookmarks.rc

I am a very good with many languages, bash isn't one of them.  I am not good with bash, casts, types, etc.

I use the linux SCREEN program ALLOT and usuaylly have a minimum of 10 windows open in screen.  I also use a very fancy prompt:

[image: prompt screenshot]

This shows me my current "project" which is simply a saved path.  Typing in "bms" is short for bookmarks, which "lists bookmarks":

[image: example project list]

Now, when I jump onto a server, the first thing I do is USUALLY to type "bm" to jump straight into the directory of the project I was working on last.  If I have to change directories to another path of a project I work on frequently, i.e., project 2 from below "toolbox", after typing "bms" to see the number associated with the path, then I simply type in "bm 2" and press return.

All of this is written as part of my .bashrc, however is separated out into a "bookmarks.rc" file which is simply sourced by my .bashrc file.

What I would REALLY like to do, is have the bookmarks storage path "~/.bookmarks.set" be a variable:

*`export BOOKMARKS='~/.bookmarks.set'`*

However,.. when I try this, I then am not able to reference it below in the rest of the file correctly.  I do not know what I am doing enough in able to do this.  As of right now the, the path is hard-coded.

SO,... I wish to GIFT his cool "program" to someone, and in return, could they please help "fix" this file, so that the rest of it utilizes the variable ***$BOOKMARKS*** which is set on line 14 [here](https://github.com/PyTis/PyTis/blob/development/src/bootstrap-box/home-jlee/bashrc/bookmarks.rc),.. or you can simply look at the code below:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) written by Josh Lee.
# Bookmark shortcuts ##
############################################################################
##  XXX-TODO (next version)
##
############################################################################
## This now keeps up to 20 lines in the file.
## Without giving a number, bm just loads the top line. setbm shifts all
## lines down one, and adds a new top line, bm again would load the top line, 
## but bm 1 or bm 2 would go back one or 2 lines down and read those instead
## (basically allowing you to keep history).  You can manage how many lines it
## keeps track of by editing the "total_bms=20" variable below

export BOOKMARKS='~/.bookmarks.set' # Where are the bookmarks stored
let total_bms=20 # How many bookmarks to track

############################################################################
# This version explained:  This is for bookmarking a single bookmark direcotry.
# Many times when working on a server, the user must change directories many
# times, however, your purpose for being on said server, is to work on a
# specific bookmark.  Perhaps you'll end up in /etc/apache2/sites-available/
# for editing the sites http conf, and then in /var/bind9/xyz, then perhaps in
# /var/lib/mysql.  Eventually however, you will always be circling back to your
# primary bookmark.  To save the time of typing out the path with "cd" (change
# direcory you now have the follwoing commands available:
# Author: Josh Lee
# Copyright: PyTis.com
# Created: June 1st, 2016
# Modified: August 19, 2022
# License: GPL
# Version: 2
#
# *** The only 2 commands you will want to memorize are: "setBm" and "bm" ***
#
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
# 
# setBm/setBookmark, setbm/setbookmark; 
#
# setBm is simply an alias of setBookmark, these are case insensative;
# These commands are for settting the current bookmark.  Look at is as
# bookmarking your bookmark.  You can call it one of 2 ways, by passing the
# current path in with '.' as the input argument, or by passing a specific path
# in, regardless of your current path (expressed with `pwd`).  The path will be
# stored in your home directory in a file named .bookmark.set 
# i.e.: ~/.bookmark.set
#
#   examples:
#     > setBm
#     > setBm .
#     > setBm /some/path/to/a/bookmark
#
# Actual Use Example:
# [ CURRENT PROJECT: ]
# ( jlee38@IP:208.127.81.217 )-[UNAME: CYGWIN_NT-10.0-19044 ]-(13:19:33 PM Thu Jul 28)
# (~/bitbucket/src_igb has 41 files, 46Kb) --> setBm
# PROJECT WAS:
# PROJECT IS NOW: '/home/jlee38/bitbucket/src_igb'
# 
# Actual Use Example:
# [ CURRENT PROJECT:/home/jlee38/bitbucket/src_igb ]
# ( jlee38@IP:208.127.81.217 )-[UNAME: CYGWIN_NT-10.0-19044 ]-(13:17:16 PM Thu Jul 28)
# (~/bitbucket/src_igb has 41 files, 46Kb) --> setBm
# NO CHANGE, PROJECT ALREADY SET TO: /home/jlee38/bitbucket/src_igb
#
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
#
# showBm/showBookmark, showbm/showbookmark; 
#
# showBm is simply an alias of showBookmark, these are case insensative;
# This command reads the current bookmark path from your user's environmental
# varialbe $PROJECT and prints it to screen; WITHOUT reading it from the user's
# ~/.bookmark.set file.
#
# Actual Use Example:
# [ CURRENT PROJECT:/home/jlee38/bitbucket/src_igb ]
# ( jlee38@IP:208.127.81.217 )-[UNAME: CYGWIN_NT-10.0-19044 ]-(13:19:52 PM Thu Jul 28)
# (~/bitbucket/src_igb has 41 files, 46Kb) --> showBm
# /home/jlee38/bitbucket/src_igb
#
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
#
# listBms/listBookmarks, listbms/listbookmarks, bms
# showBms/showBookmarks, showbms/showbookmarks; these are case insensative 
#
# This command will print out all bookmarks stored in te ~/.bookmark.set file.
#
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
#
# loadBm/loadBookmark, loadbm/loadbookmark these are case insensative
# You can enter a number, to choose a stored bookmark
#
# This command will first read the path stored in your ~/.bookmark.set file,
# load it into the environmental variable $PROJECT, then reset the bookmark in
# your current prompt, by calling _setPrompt.
#
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
# getBm/getBookmark, getbm/getbookmark:
#
# getBm is simply an alias of getBookmark, these are case insensative;
# This command will first read the path stored in your ~/.bookmark.set file,
# load it into the environmental variable $PROJECT, then reset the bookmark in
# your current prompt, then print it to screen.
# Same as calling loadBm, _setPrompt, then this prints the bookmark to the
# screen.
#
# Actual Use Example:
# [ CURRENT PROJECT:/home/jlee38/bitbucket/src_igb ]
# ( jlee38@IP:208.127.81.217 )-[UNAME: CYGWIN_NT-10.0-19044 ]-(13:29:19 PM Thu Jul 28)
# (~/bitbucket/src_igb has 41 files, 46Kb) --> getBm
# PROJECT IS:
# /home/jlee38/bitbucket/src_igb
#
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
#
# bm
#
# This command is used to jump (change directories) to the current bookmark.
# 
# Actual Use Example:
# [ CURRENT PROJECT:/home/jlee38/bitbucket/src_igb ]
# ( jlee38@IP:208.127.81.217 )-[UNAME: CYGWIN_NT-10.0-19044 ]-(13:37:39 PM Thu Jul 28)
# (~ has 35 files, 5.8Mb) --> bm
#
# [ CURRENT PROJECT:/home/jlee38/bitbucket/src_igb ]
# ( jlee38@IP:208.127.81.217 )-[UNAME: CYGWIN_NT-10.0-19044 ]-(13:37:44 PM Thu Jul 28)
# (~/bitbucket/src_igb has 41 files, 46Kb) -->
#
############################################################################
############################################################################
IP=`LANG=c getip | awk -F: '{print $1}'`

function _setPrompt() {
   export PS1="\n[ CURRENT PROJECT:\[\e[37;1m\]$PROJECT \[\e[30;1m\]]\n\[\e[30;1m\]( \[\e[1;32m\]\u\[\e[1;30m\]@IP:\[\e[0;31m\]$IP \[\e[1;30m\])-[UNAME: \[\e[2;30m\]\$(uname) \[\e[0;37m\]\[\e[1;30m\]HOST: \[\e[2;30m\]\h\[\e[0;37m\]\[\e[1;30m\] ]-(\[\e[0;32m\]\D{%H:%M:%S %p} \d\[\e[30;1m\])\[\e[30;1m\]\n(\[\e[1;33m\]\w \[\e[1;35m\]has \[\e[37;1m\]\$(/bin/ls -1 | /usr/bin/wc -l | /bin/sed 's: ::g') files, \$(/bin/ls -lah | /bin/grep -m 1 total | /bin/sed 's/total //')b\[\e[30;1m\]) --> \[\e[0m\]"
    # ^^^ I AM LOVING THIS! ^^^^^
  export PS2='-> '
  export PS4="\n"
}
function _setBookmark() {
    old="$PROJECT";
    if [ "$*" == '' ]; then
        input=`pwd`;
        input=`realpath $input`;
    else
        input=`realpath $*`;
    fi 

    if [[ "$input" == "$PROJECT" ]]; then
        echo "NO CHANGE, PROJECT ALREADY SET TO: $PROJECT";
    elif [[ "$input" != "" ]]; then
        export PROJECT=$input;
        echo "PROJECT WAS: $old";
        echo "PROJECT IS NOW: '$PROJECT' ";
    else
        noinput=`pwd`;
        if [[ "$noinput" == "$PROJECT" ]]; then
      echo "NO CHANGE, PROJECT ALREADY SET TO: $PROJECT";
        else
      export PROJECT="$noinput";
      echo "PROJECT WAS: $old";
      echo "PROJECT IS NOW: '$PROJECT' ";
        fi
    fi

  # remove it from the nth place it is in (if it is there)
  cat ~/.bookmark.set | egrep -v "$PROJECT" > ~/.bookmark.set.tmp
  
  # now put it at the top of the file
  (echo "$PROJECT"; cat ~/.bookmark.set.tmp) | head -n${total_bms} > ~/.bookmark.set

  /bin/rm ~/.bookmark.set.tmp; # >&2;

    _setPrompt;
}
function _loadBookmark() {

    if [ -f ~/.bookmark.set ]; then
    # is $i already set? did it pass through?
    re='^[0-9]+$'
    if [[ $i =~ $re ]]; then
      # use i, i is already set
      :
    elif [ "$*" == '' ]; then
      # if I isn't already set, maybe loadBookmark was called directly, we can
      # set it now, and if there was no input, use default of 1
      let  i=1;
    else
      # there was input, let's use the input
      let i=$*;
    fi 

        export PROJECT=`sed "${i}q;d" ~/.bookmark.set `;
    else
    touch ~/.bookmark.set;
        export PROJECT="~/";
    fi
  unset i;
    _setPrompt;
}
function _showBookmark() {
    echo "$PROJECT";
}
function _bm() {
  # valid input, nothing OR an Integer (or a period (.), but that is a hack)
  
  re='^[0-9]+$'
  if [[ $* =~ $re ]]; then
    # IF there is input, it IS a number, good
    :
  else
    # It is NOT a number, it better be blank then,
    if [[ $* == '' ]]; then
      # The input is blank,... good
      :
    elif [[ $* == '.' ]]; then
      # ahh, the user wants to set this as another bookmark
      _setBookmark;
      return 0;
    else
      echo "ERROR: This command takes NO INPUT or INTEGERS only.";
      return;
    fi
  fi

  if [ "$*" == '' ]; then
    # it is blank, let's just set it to 1
    let i=1;
  else
    # lets use the input the user gave us
    let i=$*;
  fi 

    _loadBookmark;

  echo "PROJECT IS NOW: $PROJECT";

    if [ $PROJECT == "~/" ]; then
        cd
    else
        cd $PROJECT;
    fi
#   _setPrompt;

}
function _getBookmark() {

  re='^[0-9]+$'
  if [[ $i =~ $re ]]; then
    # use i, i is already set
    :
  elif [ "$*" == '' ]; then
    # if I isn't already set, maybe loadBookmark was called directly, we can
    # set it now, and if there was no input, use default of 1
    let  i=1;
  else
    let i=$*;
  fi 

    _loadBookmark;
    echo -n "PROJECT IS: ";
    _showBookmark;
}
function _listBookmarks() {
  total_lines=`wc -l ~/.bookmark.set | cut -d' ' -f1 `;
  current_line=1;
  for (( c=$current_line; c<=$total_lines; c++ ))
  do
    lin=`sed "${c}q;d"  ~/.bookmark.set`;
    echo "$c: $lin";
  done
}
alias setbookmark='_setBookmark';
alias setBookmark='_setBookmark';
alias setbm='_setBookmark';
alias setBm='_setBookmark';
alias bookmark='_setBookmark';

alias showBookmark='_showBookmark';
alias showbookmark='_showBookmark';
alias showbm='_showBookmark';
alias showBm='_showBookmark';

alias listBookmarks='_listBookmarks';
alias listbookmarks='_listBookmarks';
alias listBms='_listBookmarks';
alias listbms='_listBookmarks';

alias showBookmarks='_listBookmarks';
alias showbookmarks='_listBookmarks';
alias showbms='_listBookmarks';
alias showBms='_listBookmarks';

alias loadBookmark='_loadBookmark';
alias loadbookmark='_loadBookmark';
alias loadbm='_loadBookmark';
alias loadBm='_loadBookmark';

alias getBookmark='_getBookmark';
alias getbookmark='_getBookmark';
alias getBm='_getBookmark';
alias getbm='_getBookmark';

alias setPrompt='_setPrompt';
alias bms='_listBookmarks';
alias bm='_bm'; # bm [optional NUMBER] ie: >> bm 3


#
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------


_loadBookmark;
_setPrompt;

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Specifically, I've had issues when catting the file "cat $BOOKMARKS" or when trying to read, write, etc,... so basically, not knowing how to reference the variable.

**Hey, I did good for a noob right?**

Comment: I don't think all of my documentation is up to date.  I believe that the shortcut "bm" now has many functions.  You can just type "bm" to jump to the last bookmark, "bm #' to jump to a bookmark by number, "bm ." to bookmark the current directory, or "bm [SOME/PATH]" to bookmark a path.

Comment: `I've had issues when catting the file "cat $BOOKMARKS"` What issues?

Comment: I find it odd, that you define a variable _BOOKMARKS_, but later on never use this variable, but always type out the file explicitly. This could become a maintenance problem, if you decide to change the path of the bookmark file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~` inside `'` means `~`.

```
$ echo '~'
~
$ ls '~'
ls: cannot access '~': No such file or directory
$ ls ~
 Android/ ....
```

Use `$HOME` in double quotes to expand `~` upon use.

```
export BOOKMARKS="$HOME/.bookmarks.set"
```

Your code has minor (or more) issues. Check your script with shellcheck. Also see [deprecated syntax](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete).

Comment: That may just help!  I won't be able to have time to check until tomorrow, but I am wondering if that is the only issue.  if it is or not,.. THANKS!!!
Other than that, what do you think?  It is my "first" major bash program, if you would/could call it that.

Comment: And so quickly, thank you again.  New version is available on github now, same link as above.